# How do I turn an array into an Observable in Angular 10?

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, angular-observable

I'm doing a simple display of data from a Gemini bitcoin websocket.  I am able to subscribe to the websocket and process the incoming messages in my subscribe function.  This all works as expected.  dataFromMessages changes values as I process new messages.

**What is the next step to make dataFromMessages an Observable?**

I know if it's an Observable, then I can use "| async" in my html.  Or I can subscribe to the Observable.  But I don't know how to make it an Observable.  Use the or() function?

**output.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserWebsocketService } from '../services/user-websocket.service';

export class OutputComponent implements OnInit{

  dataFromMessages;

  constructor(private websocket: UserWebsocketService){}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.websocket.connect('wss://api.gemini.com/v1/marketdata/btcusd')
    .subscribe(message => this.process_message(message));
  }

  process_message(message){
    // *** do processing here with incoming message object***
    
    this.dataFromMessages = processed_data;
  }
}
```

**output.component.html**

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr> <th>Bid</th> <th>Ask</th> </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of dataFromMessages">
      <td>{{ item.bid }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.ask }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can't you just type yourdataFromMessage as Observable and use `from()` method from rxjs ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize `dataFromMessages` as observable;

```
dataFromMessages$: Observable<any>;
```

Instead of subscribe you can use rxjs [pipe](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/pipe) and [tap](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/tap) operators to do the magic

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
   this.dataFromMessages$ = this.websocket.connect('wss://api.gemini.com/v1/marketdata/btcusd')
   .pipe(tap(message) => this.process_message(message));
}
```

And in `process_message` method return the processed message.

```
process_message(message){
   // *** do processing here with incoming message object***

   return processed_data;
}
```

And in template use async pipe to subscribe and read data.

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of dataFromMessages$ | async">
  <td>{{ item.bid }}</td>
  <td>{{ item.ask }}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I was actually just looking for the simpler answer "map" instead of "tap".  Thank you!  Is it possible to split one incoming Observable (websocket) into many Observables?  With map(), I can put all the data I need into dataFromMessages$.prices, dataFromMessages$.quantities, etc.  and subscribe to the top-level dataFromMessages$.  Is there a way to split those into separate Observables so they can each update a different section of html?  Can I set each Observable value from the map() function using dataPrices$ = of(message.prices), dataQuantities$ = of(message.quantities)?

Comment: Yeah you can give it try, lemme know if it not works.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare your dataFromMessages as an observable of the type you want.
Then in ngOnInit() use the rxjs map() operator inside a pipe to do your processing and return it. In here you can use the message "normally" and after the pipe finishes it will be an observable transformed with the operators you used inside the pipe.

Then in your HTML use the async pipe

```html
<tr *ngFor="let item of dataFromMessages$ | async">
  <td>{{ item.bid }}</td>
  <td>{{ item.ask }}</td>
</tr>
```

```js
dataFromMessages$: Observable<myDataType>;

ngOnInit(): void {
  dataFromMessages$ = this.websocket.connect('wss://api.gemini.com/v1/marketdata/btcusd').pipe(
    map(message => {

      // Do my quantum physics and message processing here

      return processed_data;
    })
  );
}
```